Join two tables and show the result in the same line
How can I write a SQL query to join the both tables (location_relation and location_name) and show the id and the name of each location in a row like this?
Sample input data - table location_relation:



id
location
location_sub




1
400
401


2
500
501


3
600
601


4
700
701



Table location_name:



id
location




400
South Africa


401
France


500
Germany


501
EUA


600
Columbia


601
Spain


700
Portugal


701
Argentina



Expected result:



location
location_sub
location
location_sub




400
401
South Africa
France


500
501
Germany
EUA


600
601
Columbia
Spain


700
701
Portugal
Argentina



My data:
create table location_relation
(
    id int,  
    location int, 
    location_sub int
);

create table location_name
(
    id int, 
    location varchar(100)
);

insert into location_relation 
values (1, 400, 401), (2, 500, 501), (3, 600, 601), (4, 700, 701);

insert into location_name 
values (400, 'South Africa'), (401, 'France'),
       (500, 'Germany'), (501, 'EUA'), 
       (600, 'Columbia'), (601, 'Spain'), 
       (700, 'Portugal'), (701, 'Argentina');

I tried something like this:
select * 
from location_relation lr 
inner join location_name ln on lr.location  = ln.id

union

select * 
from location_relation lr 
inner join location_name ln on lr.location_sub  = ln.id


Note: Since this is your first question and I wanted to be kind, I removed your image and replaced it by tables and I also added the code to create the tables with the sample data. So people have a chance to understand and solve your task. Next time, please do this work on your own. Otherwise, you will likely collect some downvotes and the question will not be answered, but closed. Thank you.

Also, whenever you ask an SQL question, please identify which DBMS you are intending to use.  There are lots of differences between different SQL DBMS, and very often the best answer varies depending on the DBMS you're using.  See also the SQL tag wiki.

To get result where both location and location_sub columns from the location_relation table are replaced with their respective names from the location_name table, you need to perform two joins:
Join the location_relation.location column with the location_name.id column to get the location name.
Join the location_relation.location_sub column with the location_name.id column to get the location_sub name.
Here's the correct SQL query for this:
sql
SELECT 
    lr.location, 
    lr.location_sub, 
    ln1.location AS location_name, 
    ln2.location AS location_sub_name
FROM 
    location_relation lr
JOIN 
    location_name ln1 ON lr.location = ln1.id
JOIN 
    location_name ln2 ON lr.location_sub = ln2.id;

what happens is:
JOIN location_name ln1 ON lr.location = ln1.id: This maps location from location_relation to the corresponding name in location_name.
JOIN location_name ln2 ON lr.location_sub = ln2.id: This maps location_sub from location_relation to the corresponding name in location_name.

I already mentioned this option in my answer, so why copy that?

@JonasMetzler: Probably because Udeshya was writing their answer while you were writing yours, and you managed to post first — that's all.

Possible of course, I just wondered because there was a lot of time between our answers. But mabye they just didn't notice. However, they used JOIN, not LEFT JOIN. I think it would be a nice improvement if they explain why.

I'd use JOIN and not LEFT JOIN unless I was told that the location_relation table was in a state of semantic disintegrity (did not have foreign key joins properly enforced).  The example data does not show any such problem.

"Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't realize our answers were quite similar — my apologies if it seemed repetitive." @JonasMetzler

"I used JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN because the requirement assumes that all location and location_sub values in location_relation have corresponding entries in location_name. If there's no guarantee of referential integrity, LEFT JOIN could be considered to avoid missing rows in the result set."

If some location_relation entries might lack corresponding names, switching to LEFT JOIN ensures all records are included, even if some lookups fail.

You haven't tagged the RDBMS you use.
In case your RDBMS provides the FILTER clause, it seems like the fastest query would be a simple JOIN with conditional aggregation using FILTER on the location type (main or sub location):
SELECT
  lr.location, 
  lr.location_sub,
  MIN(ln.location) FILTER (WHERE lr.location = ln.id) AS location,
  MIN(ln.location) FILTER (WHERE lr.location_sub = ln.id) AS location_sub
FROM
  location_relation lr
  INNER JOIN location_name ln
    ON ln.id IN (lr.location, lr.location_sub)
GROUP BY
  lr.location,
  lr.location_sub
ORDER BY
  lr.location;

For example, Postgres provides this option, as you can read in the documentation.
If the FILTER clause is not available, you could use CASE (likely a bit slower):
SELECT
  lr.location, 
  lr.location_sub,
  MIN(CASE WHEN lr.location = ln.id THEN ln.location END) AS location,
  MIN(CASE WHEN lr.location_sub = ln.id THEN ln.location END) AS location_sub
FROM
  location_relation lr
  INNER JOIN location_name ln
    ON ln.id IN (lr.location, lr.location_sub)
GROUP BY
  lr.location,
  lr.location_sub
ORDER BY
  lr.location;

Note that both above queries would fail in case multiple rows satisfy each join condition. This seems to be no valid use case in your situation, but it should be mentioned.
Obviously, you could also join two times, but this seems to be the slowest option because it needs to query the table one more time. But it would of course return all rows for multiple matches.
SELECT
  lr.location, 
  lr.location_sub,
  ln1.location,
  ln2.location AS location_sub
FROM
  location_relation lr
  LEFT JOIN location_name ln1
    ON ln1.id = lr.location
  LEFT JOIN location_name ln2
    ON ln2.id = lr.location_sub
ORDER BY
  lr.location;

The execution times mostly depends on indices and real data, so I recommend to just try out a bit.
In this sample fiddle, the fastest query was the first of this answer.
